# Basic prepared statement not INSERTING

Tags: php, mysql

I am for the first time trying to build a simple form to insert data to a MySQL table. It is not working however.

This is the form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
Select Park : <select name="park_id">
              <option value="">Select Park</option>

              <?php foreach ($res as $row) {

              printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>' . PHP_EOL, $row['park_id'], $row['name']);

               } ?>

    </select>

Headline: <input type="text" name="headline">
<br>
Story: <input type="textbox" name="story">
<br>
Date: <input type="date" name="date">

Password :<input type="password" value="" name="password" id="password">

<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and this is the php:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tpf_newstest(headline,story,date,park_id) VALUES(:headline,:story,:date,:park_id)");
$stmt->execute(array(':headline' => $headline, ':story' => $story, ':date' => $date, ':park_id' => $park_id));
$affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
}
```

It it all within the same index.php file. Any ideas as to what I've done wrong?
Thanks

EDIT: if it helps this is the full page

```
try
{
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=*', '*','******');

    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
}
    catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $output = 'Unable to connect to the database server.';
    include 'output.html.php';
    exit();
}

$output = 'Theme Park Database initialized';


$qry = "select park_id, name from tpf_parks order by name";
$res = $pdo->query($qry);


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tpf_newstest(headline,story,date,park_id) VALUES(:headline,:story,:date,:park_id)");
$stmt->execute(array(':headline' => $headline, ':story' => $story, ':date' => $date, ':park_id' => $park_id));
$affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
}

?>

<form action="" method="post">
Select Park : <select name="park_id">
              <option value="">Select Park</option>

              <?php foreach ($res as $row) {

              printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>' . PHP_EOL, $row['park_id'], $row['name']);

               } ?>

    </select>

Headline: <input type="text" name="headline">
<br>
Story: <input type="textbox" name="story">
<br>
Date: <input type="date" name="date">

Password :<input type="password" value="" name="password" id="password">

<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like you're connecting to your DB. Least I don't see anything, to my eyes anyway. Or did you leave that part out?

Comment: HTML and php are on the same page?

Comment: It does connect, I left that part out

Comment: Yes, all on the same page first my db connect script, then the php insert script then the html form

Comment: @user2574794 Well then, may I suggest that you include that wee-bit of information in your question? That way, you will avoid others asking the same question, as many a time, that is a mistake that people make. Just trying to avoid confusion here. ;-)

Comment: It makes the connection becuase it populates the drop down with values from a table

Comment: Did you forget the form action or did you remove it before posting here?

Comment: @TomasCreemers The action is probably set that way, because everything is probably happening on the same page.

Comment: @user2574794 How are you populating `$headline` etc?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson headline, story are text boxes, park_id is dropdown, date pops up a calender

Comment: No errors, once submit is clicked the form resets

Comment: @user2574794 Yes, but you're never setting the variables before using them as far as I can see...? `$headline = $_POST['headline'];` etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that there is no field named `submit` at all in the $_POST, so the code of inserting will not be executed. To fix this problem, instead of check `submit` field, you may check other fields, such as `park_id`, `date` and so on.

Hope helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is no `name` for submit. so how can `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` become true? you can adjust the html as follows and try

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: this seems to have helped becuase I now at least get an error `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home3/danville/public_html/test3/index.php on line 31` line 31 is `$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tpf_newstest(headline,story,date,park_id) VALUES(:headline,:story,:date,:park_id)");`